# Why does the Number() method increment the value of a number when the length of the number is greater than 15?

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

Whenever I run this, the number returned gets incremented, can anyone explain this to me?

```
let array = [9, 2, 2, 3, 3, 7, 2, 0, 3, 6, 8, 5, 4, 7, 7, 1]
return Number(array.join(''))
```

Outputs:

```
9223372036854772
```

Comment: See this [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104391/why-do-javascript-converts-some-number-values-automatically)

Answer (score 9):

The number is larger than [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) (2<sup>53</sup>-1). You may want to use [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) instead.

Example:

```js
let array = [9, 2, 2, 3, 3, 7, 2, 0, 3, 6, 8, 5, 4, 7, 7, 1]
let num = BigInt(array.join(''));
console.log(num.toString());
console.log("Doubled:", (num * 2n).toString());
console.log("Squared:", (num ** 2n).toString());
```

You can use [`Number.isSafeInteger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger) to check if a value is precise.

```js
let array = [9, 2, 2, 3, 3, 7, 2, 0, 3, 6, 8, 5, 4, 7, 7, 1]
let num = Number(array.join(''));
console.log("Safe?", Number.isSafeInteger(num));
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of `array.join('')` is `"9223372036854772"`.  That is much larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.  `Number` constructor can't precisely hold numbers greater than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, and therefore you get this error.  You might want to use something like a `BigInt` for handling such large numbers.